# Farming Varkid morph pods

Tags: borderlands-2

Since a varkid adult morph pod gives you 1000ish XP, is it a recommended way to level up quickly?

I am a level 38 gunzerker on TVHM.

If so, which area is better: Tundra Express **OR** Caustic Caverns?

Comment: That is fairly safe xp but after you kill them the wait on the respawn timer is not great.  I would say do a circle of slaughter until round 5 and then deliberately fail and re-do it.  The animal one is in the wildlife exploitation preserve, the bandit one is right at the fast-travel in the fridge and the robot one is in eridium blight. I happen to like the bandit one.

Comment: Is getting slaughtered after killing a few 2 or 3 enemies normal in the bandit one? >.>

Comment: depends on your gear and what round you are in. In round 1 the enemies are scaled to be close or below your level. In round 3 and up they are usually 1 or 2 above you.  By Round 5 they can be closer to 3 or 4 levels above you and there are quite a few badasses. If you are having trouble try using more fire elemental weapons and don't be afraid to move around a lot.  You play on X-box, PC or PS3?  If X-box add me and i will be happy to join ya tomorrow night.

Comment: @BrandonBouquillon Sorry, PS3.

Comment: Arid Nexus? You mean Tundra Express, right? There are no Varkids in Arid Nexus

Comment: @BenBrocka Oh yea, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which I would recommend personally; you can freely run around Tundra Express to find all the Varkid pods (TE and Caustic Caverns are the only places with Varkids so I assume that's what you meant, not Arid Nexus), while Caustic Caverns throws many more tough enemies between sets of Varkids. I do believe there are less varkids overall in Caustic Caverns, but there are two clusters with great numbers of them (at the very start, and midway into the level after the first set of Treshers and before the Spiderants).

However Caustic Caverns spawns you closer to the first set of Varkids so you could more easily farm, quit, rejoin, then farm the respawned varkids and repeat, plus they should be of a higher level. As a bonus, the Chubby Varkid sometimes spawns at the start of the Caverns so you might get some decent loot out of it as well.

Also note that unless you've finished the game again in TVHM mode the enemies won't scale, so you're probably better off in Caustic Caverns either way as long as the enemies levels are higher (though if the enemy is at your level or higher, level distance no longer matters and you'll get full XP from that enemy).

However as far as "recommended", I really wouldn't recommend grinding levels unless you've actually hit a brick wall (we sure did at the boss of the Wildlife Exploitation Preserve), since by the end of the game you're almost sure to be level 49/50 (I've see 3 people, myself included, reach 50 during/after the final fight) even without too many side missions. Grinding should really be reserved for level 50 loot unless you feel you need it; keep up normal progression and you'll level well enough, the enemy levels/XP balancing is quite well designed (if a bit difficult) for even playthrough 2.

Comment: By maths, I don't really think you can get to 49/50 after TVHM o_O

Comment: @Meraj99 you'd be surprised, in my experience you keep pace (within 2 levels) with enemy levels pretty easily, and enemies are level 50 by the final mission. You'll need to take some side missions but not many; I'd recommend avoiding any missions with blue loot or better (so you can do them later and get the level 50 loot for them)

Comment: I completely agree with Ben Brocka on saving the side missions with blue or better loot rewards for after completeing playthrough 2. I gave up on my Gunzerker because i just could not seem to make the class useful enough. that said i had alrerady played 2 soldiers to 50 (one powerleveled one just regular playing) and a siren and those 2 classes are very strong and it kind of spoiled me. I would say just keep fighting through the story and try to get into some groups if ya can. Multiplayer is what this game is all about anyway.

Comment: @BrandonBouquillon how rare, someone who played commando (who wasn't playing solo!), Gunzerker can be good too, though I do prefer my Siren/mechro

Comment: I take back what I said. From the moment I began combining the skill "moneyshot" and dual wielding two Double-Penetrating Unkempt Harold pistols, I was able to take down virtually any target with my Gunzerker. The class is great, I was just playing it wrong.